# Can I start a windows form from a console program

Tags: winforms

I'd like to start a new windows form from a console program. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean load a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` instance from within a Console application, or start a Windows Forms program from a console app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a reference to Windows.Forms, then:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Form()); //of course you can put your own custom Form here.
}
```

Comment: Yup; if this is what he meant (rather than starting a separate Forms app), this is the correct answer. This is the easiest way to get a WinForms app with a Console, by the way; as opposed to creating a Forms app and trying to get a Console, you create a Console app, add the right refs, and add a Form.

Comment: What's the difference between this solution and create a winform application?

Comment: @user496949: The difference is that it's a console application.

Comment: I just wasn't sure from what you asked if you meant doing this, or having a console application that starts up a totally separate WinForms app. Of course that is easy to do - you start it like any other program - but weird things happen if your console program isn't running in the context of a user login. (same with this, actually...)

Answer (score -1):

Use "start"

C:> start yourprogram.exe

Comment: He's asking about doing it from a console *program*; not from the console directly.