# C# Show Form Creates a new Form.. Not the one I designed

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have a console application made and a design of a settings windows form too. What i want to do is, show the windows form after a specific event.

The design of the form contains buttons, menustrips etc.. here is the code i use to display it

```
Settings frmSettings = new Settings();
frmSettings.ShowDialog();
```

The problem is, when the Settings form is shown, it is not the one i designed.. It is completely empty. How can I make the app to load the one I have designed??

Comment: Can you show the code around your display code?

Comment: You "have a console application made"???  Console applications don't show forms.  Make a winforms application.

Comment: @Scott I know that.. I want to link a WinForm to a console app.. As in, in the console after a specific event, a new WINFORM will show.. If I use the code I stated above, a blank one is shown but I need the one which I designed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I start a windows form from a console program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495574/can-i-start-a-windows-form-from-a-console-program)

Comment: but then why does the empty form start?

Comment: The better question would be: is the form responsive at all?  (As there's a difference between having it show, and having it respond - the latter would require the event loop to be running.)  In either case, take a look at the linked duplicate.  It seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh nvm I found the way

Comment: If the way is different than that posted in the duplicate question, make sure to put your answer here (or there, or both), so others can learn from your experience.  :-)

Comment: no the duplicate link is alright..thanks a lot

Comment: Also, when Scott said here, he meant in an answer, not edited into the question.

Comment: I am not able to add an answer before 8 hours due to low reputation

Comment: Then put into a comment that you've resolved it by adding those lines, and add that you will post an answer once you can (removing the comment once the answer is up). I can't imagine people being too worked up if you actually did that and followed through in a reasonably quick manner.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: FIXED

I posted this under the main void of Program.CS and it worked (Had to link the windows forms to it)

```
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new About());
```